# $.getScript returns status canceled and the application does not execute the callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-codes, getscript

### Environment

To automate the compression and the junction of my js files, I use [this](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Microsoft.Web.Optimization) tool.

Once installed and configured, the code below returns a js compressed and concatenated with all the JS folder `project`

`<script src="@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/pages/project-projectPhotos/js")"></script>`

### Problem

In my page, have the following code:

```
loaderPhotosPage = function(url) {
  $.getScript('/Scripts/pages/project-projectPhotos/js', function() {
    alert(url); //This code is not executed!! Here's the problem;
  });
};
```

`alert` is never executed!

### Tests

To simulate a test tool using Google Chrome Developer Tools, I got the following results:

**Code executed on Google Chrome Developer**

Look at the console, and the header. The execution is very successful!

[image: Code executed on Google Chrome Developer]

Now the preview result

[image: Result of script on Google Chrome Developer]

The HTTP status is as canceled, why? Yet the code in the console was running normally (**text: success**)

[image: Http Status]

I put the js file complete at [this](https://gist.github.com/1385633) link.

### Another test:

See the get, with the link of the script is running normally!

[image: Get Script]

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: thing you made a typo at `function() { alert(url); }` cause url isn't defined in that context

Comment: Still did not work!
I noticed that when I click again, the second click it works! The callback function is executed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canceled status is an issue with current dev channel Google Chrome. It has been fixed upstream and will propagate to the dev channel accordingly.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72873